# Corda: Unclear corda error code with a dead link

Tags: corda

I came across an error message when running Corda Enterprise. I was able to solve the error. But the link at the end of the error message caught my attention.

`[ERROR] 16:28:02+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: certificate key must be an instance of java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey or sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey [errorCode=fnu1lw, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.0/fnu1lw]`

This link is linked to a page that needs a login. And errors.corda.net is a dead link, too. What is the logic behind this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an error occurs, the link that you see will do one of the followings:

1. try to find a Stack Overflow post that specifically answer to the error code (it is the `fnu1lw` in your case) and redirect to the page.
2. take you to the enterprise support site when it can't find a S/O post that is specific to the error code (as it was assumed that Enterprise customers would have a support contract).

Since you are running Corda Enterprise, so it takes you to the login page of Corda enterprise support.